# Java Android ArrayList with Id

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have ten numberDecimal inputs with names input_1, input_2,...,input_10.
In the mainActivity I'm getting theirs IDs by this way

```
EditText input_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_1);
EditText input_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_2);
...
EditText input_10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_10);
```

So I was wondering is there any way to get the IDs with FOR or any other cycle and arrays. For example something like this

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++) {
 EditText input_i = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_i);
}
```

I've tried this but it didn't work. 
Sorry for my english and thank you in advance :)

Comment: print the xml where you are using this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Context.getResources()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29), then [`Resources.getResourceIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to get the identifier of your edittext :

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++) {
    int resourceIdentifier = this.getResources().getResourceIdentifier("input_".concat(String.valueOf(i));
    EditText input_i = (EditText) findViewById(resourceIdentifier, "id", this.getPackageName()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Array of EditText and then Access this Array of EditText

```
Integer[] input_edit={R.id.input_1, R.id.input_2, R.id.input_3};


for (int i = 0; i < input_edit.length; i++) {
 EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(input_edit[i]);
**Then put this EditText Value in any Array if you need to work out side of this loop**         
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a efficient way of doing that.
I used 2 methods, they are: **getResource()** and **getIdentifier()**

The first one is used to get access to the resources of your applicacion for example: you could use it to get a reference to a string using `getResource().getString(id)` or a drawable using `getResource().getDrawable(id)`. You can get more info about its method here: [Resources Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)

The second one is a method from Resource class used to get an ID.

```
 EditText input;

for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){

  //here you get the id

 int current_id =  this.getResources().getIdentifier("input_".concat(String.valueOf(i)), "id" ,getPackageName());

 //here you set the id
 input = (EditText) findViewById(current_id);

}
```

`getIdentifier()` needs 3 arguments and they are: `(String name, String defType, String defPackage)`

You can read about them here: [Resource documentation (GetIdentifier() Method)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)